# correct way to migrate a sybase database to new hardware

Tags: database, migration, data-migration, sap-ase

I have a small Sybase ASE 15 database on a box that is scheduled to be de-commissioned. What is the best way to "clone" or "transfer" my database to the new box?

I tried to use the migration utility that comes with ASE 15 but it seems to never make it very far before big errors show up. The farthest its gotten was the creation of one table and no data ;[

I was thinking the best way would be to generate some sort of giant DDL that encompases the entire set of users, tables, and views. I have no idea how to generate this though.

Looking online it seems very difficult to find any sybase backup or migration information other than whats in sybooks ( which is hard to follow for a novice ).

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way to migrate all db objects is Michael Peppler's script dbscheme.pl http://www.peppler.org/downloads/dbschema-2_4_2.zip

I have used it with success many times in production.